# Is this a bad use of a static property?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dependency-injection, static-members

If I have a class with a service that I want all derived classes to have access to (say a security object, or a repository) then I might do something like this:

```
public abstract class A
{
    static ISecurity _security;
    public ISecurity Security { get { return _security; } }

    public static void SetSecurity(ISecurity security) { _security = security; }
}

public class Bootstrapper
{
    public Bootstrapper()
    {
        A.SetSecurity(new Security());
    }
}
```

It seems like lately I see static properties being shunned everywhere as something to absolutely avoid.  To me, this seems cleaner than adding an ISecurity parameter to the constructor of every single derived class I make.  Given all I've read lately though, I'm left wondering:

Is this is an acceptable application of dependency injection or am I violating some major design principle that could come back to haunt me later?  I am not doing unit tests at this point so maybe if I were then I would suddenly realize the answer to my question.  To be honest though I probably won't change my design over that, but if there is some other important reason why I should change it then I very well might.

**Edit**:  I made a couple stupid mistakes the first time I wrote that code... it's fixed now.  Just thought I'd point that out in case anyone happened to notice :)

**Edit**:  SWeko makes a good point about all deriving classes having to use the same implementation.  In cases where I've used this design, the service is always a singleton so it effectively enforces an already existing requirement.  Naturally, this would be a bad design if that weren't the case.

Comment: What are accessors here for? Because `_security` might as well be public in the code you've presented.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz Sorry, totally forgot to tag the language: C#.  Yes, I could have just as well made it public.  The idea though is that I want to make it available to deriving classes as an instance property.  Ideally yes I would inject it on construction of class A but to clarify why I don't do that I just made it abstract as I should have done when I first wrote it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This design could be problematic for a couple of reasons.

You already mention unit testing, which is rather important. Such static dependency can make testing much harder. When the fake `ISecurity` ever has to be anything else than a [Null Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) implementation, you will find yourself having to removing the fake implementation on test tear down. Removing it during test tear down prevents other tests from being influenced when you forget to remove that fake object. A test tear down makes your test more complicated. Not that much complicated, but having this adds up when many tests have tear down code and you'll have a hard time finding a bug in your test suit when one test forget to run the tear down. You will also have to make sure the registered `ISecurity` fake object is thread-safe and won't influence other tests that might run in parallel (test frameworks such as MSTest run tests in parallel for obvious performance reasons).

Another possible problem with injecting the dependency as static, is that you force this `ISecurity` dependency to be a singleton (and probably to be thread-safe). This disallows for instance to apply any interceptors and [decorators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that have a different lifestyle than singleton

Another problem is that removing this dependency from the constructor disables any analysis or diagnostics that could be done by the DI framework on your behalf. Since you manually set this dependency, the framework has no knowledge about this dependency. In a sense you move the responsibility of managing dependencies back to the application logic, instead of allowing the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) to be in control over the way dependencies are wired together. Now the application has to know that `ISecurity` is in fact thread-safe. This is a responsibility that in general belongs to the Composition Root.

The fact that you want to store this dependency in a base type might even be an indication of a violation of a general design principle: The [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (SRP). It has some resemblance with a design mistake I made myself in the past. I had a set of business operations that all inherited from a base class. This base class implemented all sorts of behavior, such as transaction management, logging, audit trailing, adding fault tolerance, and.... adding security checks. This base class became an unmanageable [God Object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object). It was unmanageable, simply because it had too many responsibilities; it violated the SRP. [Here's my story](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91) if you want to know more about this.

So instead of having this security concern (it's probably a cross-cutting concern) implemented in a base class, try removing the base class all together and use a decorator to add security to those classes. You can wrap each class with one or more decorators and each decorator can handle one specific concern. This makes each decorator class easy to follow because they will follow the SRP.

Comment: +1 Great answer.  Particularly the last two paragraphs caught my attention, because they answered the underlying issue.  Sure it's great to write code that is more testable, but generally the 'reason' it's more testable is because of a more foundational issue which is what I was trying to find out.  Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so now that I have a slightly improved conceptual understanding maybe you could also give me a little direction in a practical application of this knowledge:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631660/unclear-on-how-to-implement-dependency-injection

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that is not really dependency injection, even if it is encapsulated in the definition of the class. Admittedly,

```
static Security _security;
```

would be worse than `Security`, but still, the instances of `A` do not get to use whatever security the caller passed to them, they need to *depend* on the global setting of a static property.

What I'm trying to say is that your usage is not that different from:

```
public static class Globals
{
   public static ISecurity Security {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: I think you'd agree that I am legitimately injecting the dependency into the base class, right?  So wouldn't you say that the dependency of the derived classes isn't really on a particular implementation, but rather that they all must use the same implementation?

Comment: And just in case you missed it, I edited my post to make A abstract so there won't be any instances of A.  Not that that really affects your point since it applies to derived classes just the same, but just thought I'd make note of it.

Comment: +1 because that's a great point that I didn't originally cover in my post.  And I would love to hear your thoughts about my above comment when you get a chance.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice you'd edited your post when I wrote the last comment.  And in reponse to that edit:  I think that's exactly what Bartek was pointing out also.  Perhaps I should have just written the code that way so as not to confuse the question because I'm still wondering what's wrong with doing it that way (in light of my last edit).